# How can I make a mysql query dependent on which item is clicked?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, this question is hard to explain. Basically I set up a website with news headlines in a column, and a blank white space right next to it, where the full news is supposed to be displayed when you click a headline. I'm assuming I'd need to set up a php, which echoes the database content, but is dependent on the link which is clicked. Since I did not make it further than this (I'm rather new to php), I hope someone can help me there (if this is possible at all).

I will attach the php code of the news headlines. 
The database which needs to be accessed is called "events" for both the headline (called "title" in the code) and the short summary (called "summary"), aswell as the full text (called "newstext").

Thanks in advance!

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("events") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 0, 1;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<div style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;">';
echo $row["Title"];
echo '</div>';
echo $row["summary"];
```

Comment: How do let the server now that anything was clicked at all? Did you add links to the headlines or do you use JS to invoke an AJAX call?

Comment: Broad process: 1) JS listens for link clicks; 2) JS fires an AJAX request to PHP script passing along info re: what link was clicked; 3) PHP page receives this info and queries DB accordingly; 4) PHP echos out AJAX response; 5) JS receives response and inserts content into DOM. Look into AJAX requests if you're unfamiliar.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should've specified that. I haven't finished making the column list php echoes clickable yet, as I figured it'd make more sense to know if/how this was possible first.. For now, I'm thinking of embedding the echo in a html link tag, as I have no other solution for linking yet..

Comment: Thanks for the responses, both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Give IDs to all items and then write onclick="GetID()"

```
function GetID(element) {   
    var ID = $(element).attr("id");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/yourphp.php?clickedid=ID";
}
```

and in yourphp.php

```
if(isset($_GET['clickedid']))
{
      $ID = $_GET['clickedid'];
}
```

Comment: does anyone know how to give reputation here?

Comment: if you want to give reputation just click on upvote(down of 1 Answer)

Comment: ahh i need 15 reputation to do this, sorry! I'll come back as soon as I got them